# CodeDOM compiler error, no main entry point

Tags: c#, codedom

I'm using the code:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.ShowDialog();
        string source = Properties.Resources.source;
        CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        string Output = sfd.FileName + ".exe";
        System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
        parameters.CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe";
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Management.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll");
        parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll");
        CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, Properties.Resources.source);

        if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error on line #" + CompErr.Line + " " + CompErr.ErrorText);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Compiled.");
        }
```

To compile my source, which is:

```
using System; 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Error on line #0 Program 'c:\Users\Tom\Desktop\s.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
```

From Googling and looking here, I am unable to find why this is throwing an error..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
}
```

This is also not working, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Lashane just fixed the tags

Comment: First off, this code shouldn't compile as-is, because `Main` is not in a class. If it is (and you should show the class definition), then the problem is because `Main` is not `public`.

Comment: Drew, I just fixed that and it's still not working.

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you absolutely sure `Properties.Resources.source` contains what you think it should?